GODOT 4.0 MultiPlayer FPS Server Shooting Not Working
im making a 3d multiplayer fps in godot after adding mp and upnp capabilities my shooting function stoped working i added print statments both in the function and when the input is registered, it will inconsistently work displaying animation, and printing in console (unknown atm about raycast)
aswell as the sprint not working (will display speed in console at 8.7 but will not increese)
Player Code
    extends CharacterBody3D

signal health_changed(health)

# gets outsiders 
@onready var Player = $"."
@onready var cam = $Camera3D
@onready var animPlayer = $AnimationPlayer
@onready var muzzle_flash = $Camera3D/pistol/muzzleFlash
@onready var raycast = $Camera3D/RayCast3D

# public variables
@export var health = 3
@export var SPEED = 8.7
@export var JUMP_VELOCITY = 6.8

# cans and cants
var canDoubleJump = false
var canSprint = true

# set World variables
var gravity = 20.0

func _enter_tree():
    set_multiplayer_authority(str(name).to_int())

# handle mice
func _ready():
    if not is_multiplayer_authority(): return
    
    Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED
    cam.current = true

func _unhandled_input(event):
    if not is_multiplayer_authority(): return
    # alex the mice moover
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        rotate_y(-event.relative.x * .005)  
        cam.rotate_x(-event.relative.y * .005)
        cam.rotation.x = clamp(cam.rotation.x, -PI/2, PI/2)

    # shootermc shoots alot
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("shoot"):
        print("shot")
        play_shoot_effect.rpc()
        if raycast.is_colliding():
            var hit_player = raycast.get_collider()
            hit_player.recive_damage.rpc_id(hit_player.get_multiplayer_authority())

#mostly movement
func _physics_process(delta):
    if not is_multiplayer_authority(): return
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta

    # Handle jump and double jump
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and canDoubleJump == true:
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY
        canDoubleJump = false
    else:
        pass
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY
        canDoubleJump = true

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    var input_dir = Input.get_vector("left", "right", "up", "down")
    var direction = (transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)).normalized()
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction.x * SPEED
        velocity.z = direction.z * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
        velocity.z = move_toward(velocity.z, 0, SPEED)
        
        # Sprinting
    if Input.is_action_pressed("boost") and canSprint == true:
        print(SPEED)
        SPEED = 13.2
    else:
        SPEED = 8.7
        
        # Crouching
    if Input.is_action_pressed("crouch"):
        Player.scale.y = .5
        cam.position.y = 1.119
        SPEED = 5.9
        canSprint = false
    else:
        Player.scale.y = 1
        cam.position.y = 1.619
        SPEED = 8.7
        canSprint = true
        
    # Pistol Anims
    if animPlayer.current_animation == "Shoot":
        pass
    elif input_dir != Vector2.ZERO and is_on_floor():
        animPlayer.play("Move")
    else: animPlayer.play("Idle")

    move_and_slide()
    
@rpc("call_local")
func play_shoot_effect():
    print("shoot")
    animPlayer.stop()
    animPlayer.play("Shoot")
    muzzle_flash.restart()
    muzzle_flash.emitting = true

@rpc("any_peer")
func recive_damage():
    health -= 1
    if health <= 0:
        health = 3
        position = Vector3.ZERO
        health_changed.emit(health)
        

func _on_animation_player_animation_finished(anim_name):
    if anim_name == "Shoot":
        animPlayer.play("Idle")


